# Projects that were build with GWT

Tags: gwt, projects

I was wondering which projects were build in GWT? Especially by Google itself...

Answer (score 4):

http://gwtgallery.appspot.com/ seems to be a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

[AdWords](http://adwords.google.com), [AdSense](http://adsense.google.com), [Google Health](http://www.google.com/health), [Wave](http://wave.google.com)...

Answer (score 3):

I work on [mapfaire.com](http://www.mapfaire.com)

Comment: I just quit my day job to see if I can make a business out of it. Take a look at dev.mapfaire.com if you're interested in following the development branch :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the search functionality first next time. [Projects that were build with GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949044/projects-that-were-build-with-gwt/3949063#3949063)

Answer (score 0):

Google Wave is the only one that I'm sure of (that was built by Google).

Here's another list of [applications that use GWT](http://www.gwtsite.com/whos-using-gwt/).

Comment: The recent rewrite of Google AdWords's UI was also done in GWT.

Answer (score 0):

new UI for blogger.com (avi at draft.blogger.com) is also built with GWT.