# Any success stories for JSF, GWT, Wicket or Tapestry on the web?

Tags: jsf, gwt, wicket, tapestry

I am searching for framework references. In other words I am looking for companies, which have successfully implemented a framework solution in java web application environment (success stories). Frameworks I am interested in are JSF, GWT, Wicket and Tapestry. I wasn't able to google any results, nor to find any references at the official sites. At the end I am a bit confused if there are any. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more webresearches resulted in nice findings:

Wicket: http://web.me.com/jonathan.locke/JonathanLocke/Wicket.html
Tapestry: http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/PoweredByTapestry and http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/SuccessStories
JSF: http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Projects/RealWorldJSFLinks

If you can find anymore, plz let me know :)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949044/projects-that-were-build-with-gwt/4283479#4283479 for a complete list for GWT projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of JSF, Wicket and Tapestry based apps, but Google Wave, Adwords, Adsense are built using GWT

Answer (score 0):

mobile.walmart.com, that surely has some serious traffic, is built with Wicket.

One of the reasons to go for Wicket was the complete decoupling of code and markup. The site serves three different kinds of HTML for different classes off mobile devices from the exact same code on the server.

http://www.dzone.com/links/apache_wicket_powers_mobilewalmartcom.html

Answer (score 0):

[Websites based on Wicket](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/websites-based-on-wicket.html) seems to be the largest list of Wicket websites out there.

For what it's worth, I was the architect on one of those sites, a financial services portal.  There were three other developers, two of them were GWT fans.  I haven't kept in touch with one of them, but the other has started his own company using Wicket, leaving GWT in the process.  I personally don't like GWT because of the javascript compilation.  Wicket has excellent ability to keep markup and code separated throughout the product lifecycle, something that is very hard to do with many technologies.  I was a fan of Tapestry for a while, that is until I found Wicket.

Two other frameworks that are JVM based and worth considering are [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) (uses Scala) and [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/). People who love Scala swear by it, and after seeing a demo of it, I have to admit I want to start using it soon too.